# Calculus question - Trig Identities

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Alright so I've got the question:

$\int2\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)dx$

And in class I learned:

$\sin^2(x) = ((1-\cos(2x))/2)$

$\cos^2(x) = ((1+\cos(2x))/2)$

So when I substitute I get:

$\int2((1-\cos(2x))/2)((1+\cos(2x))/2)dx$

But according to the almighty wolfram, those two aren't the same integral. What did I do wrong? And furthermore, how to I proceed?

Comment: You should use LaTeX for the math parts of your questions. It makes people answer faster.

Comment: $\int 2 sin^{2}x cos^{2}xdx$?
do you know $2 sin x cos x = sin 2x $?

Comment: I'm having trouble finding a LaTeX tutorial online. Could you point me to one?

Comment: Ah nvm, someone edited my post and I looked at the edits, pretty straight forward.

Comment: @InBetween: http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf

Comment: Not the same integral?  Perhaps they differ by a constant...

Comment: @InBetween - I would also recommend http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I put each of them into WolframAlpha, I got the same thing:

[image: original integral]

[image: second integral]

However, if I were evaluating your original integral by hand, I'd probably have used the identity $\sin 2x=2\sin x\cos x$ first (any time I see $\sin x\cos x$, that identity comes to mind).

Comment: Ah, I was missing a set a parenthesis. Dumb mistake. Thanks for the help and the other identity!

Comment: @InBetween: Wolfram Alpha gives you a fairly nicely formatted display of what it "thinks" you mean.  It pays to look carefully at that display.